# XOR instruction unicycle data path for MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, xor

This is a problem that has been giving me a headache for a while. The task is to describe the datapath that xor $s0, $s1, $s2 should have. I've been having trouble finding any information at all on how the datapath of this instruction should look like.  I know that it might be similar to any other R type instruction, but it's not shown anywhere. Any help/hint on what to do in order to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that it might be similar to any other R type instruction, but it's not shown anywhere.

Probably not shown anywhere because all R-Type instructions share the same datapath.  `XOR` *is* an R-Type instruction — there is no difference with other R-Type instructions on datapath.

What do *all* R-Type instructions do for datapath?  They fetch values from the register file based on `rs` and `rt` register numbers in those respective fields in the instruction, and forward those values to the ALU.  They take the ALU output and redirect that back to the registers to write that result to the `rd` register number.  (And they instruct the processor to increment the program counter for sequential execution.)

There is single control signal (i.e. not datapath) difference that the `ALU Control` outputs a value that tells the ALU to do the `XOR` operation instead of some other ALU operation, like `add`, `and`, `or`.  The ALU Control realizes that the ALUOp (signal from main Control) merely indicates R-Type instruction and thus the ALU Control decodes the `func` field instruction bits into that indicator to the ALU to do `XOR`.

The selection of the control signal value is generally not shown (diagrammed), but rather the values are usually found in some table that augments the datapath & control signal diagram.

Comment: I have to figure out what control signal changes in order to do that xor operation then, which I do not see clearly, but thank you so much for such an in depth answer.

Comment: I mentioned which one changes, it is the output of ALU Control that feeds to the ALU itself. It is often unlabeled but sometimes labeled "ALU Operation" (not to be confused with the ALUOp that comes out of Control).

Comment: Would you change anything inside the ALU itself? Or is it just the output of ALU control

Comment: Decode the `XOR` control signal, and activate(mux) the output of the xor function to the main ALU output (which would also turn off output from add/sub/and and the other ALU functions..).

Comment: That would maintain previous operations aswell?